# Grant different levels of access to a file for three different users

Tags: permissions, files, users

I have made 3 users with `adduser`.
How can I give each user different permissions to one file (`example.txt`) without `setfacl`?

Example:

- First user to have only read permissions to the file
- Second to have read and write permissions
- Third to have all permissions for the file.

Comment: Hi, im searching from 4 days ,please if you know how to make it  show me . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [permissions tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/info) is a nice short reference on classic Linux file permissions.

As a brief demonstration of the simplest usage of these permissions on files only, let's create a file, which I am going to call `shiny`

```
touch shiny
```

let's take a look at the permissions of the file we just created

```
$ ls -l shiny
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zanna zanna 0 Feb 26 21:54 shiny
```

The string at the start shows the permissions in sets of three. After the permissions string, there's a number that isn't interesting to us, then the word `zanna` repeated twice. `zanna` is my username. Since I created the file, I am the owner, and it belongs to my group too.

[image]

`r` = read `w` = write, `x` = execute `-` = no permission

Looking at `shiny` now we can see it is a regular file (`-` at the start) and the owner, `zanna`, may read and write to the file. Members of the group `zanna` may also read and write to the file, and any other user may read, but not write. No user has execute permission for this file.

The `stat` command gives much more detail about file metadata, including permissions, and we can format its output in various ways. For example, [my favourite way](https://askubuntu.com/a/152003/527764):

```
$ stat -c "%n %a" shiny
shiny 664
```

This shows us that the file has octal permissions 664 - read-write for owner and group, and read-only for others.

On my system I have created three user accounts, `zanna`, `pixie` and `mermaid`

Let's change the permissions of `shiny` to grant different levels of access to each user.

First, we'll create a new group (we could just add a user to the `zanna` group, but I would rather not do that, as that would give them access to lots of my personal files)

```
sudo addgroup unicorns
```

And now we'll use the `unicorns` group to control access, by making this group own `shiny`:

```
chown :unicorns shiny
```

Please do not forget the colon `:` in this command, as this allows us to change only the group, and always type carefully when using `chown` (**ch**ange **own**er) or `chmod` (**ch**ange **mod**e), especially with `sudo`.

Now make one user a member of this group:

```
sudo adduser pixie unicorns
```

Now pixie is <del>a unicorn</del> a member of the `unicorns` group.

Now we just need to change the file mode. There are two ways to do this, the octal way, which I prefer:

```
chmod 764 shiny
```

and the symbolic way:

```
chmod u+x shiny
```

I trust you to read the [chmod](/questions/tagged/chmod) wiki to learn more about these. After running one of these commands, you can check again with `stat` or `ls -l`.

```
$ ls -l shiny
-rwxrw-r-- 1 zanna unicorns 0 Feb 26 21:54 shiny
```

Now:

- `zanna` has read, write and execute permission because she is the owner
- `pixie` has read and write permission because she is in the group `unicorns`
- `mermaid` has read permission because `shiny` is readable to all.

Comment: @GeorgiBangeev It's a pleasure :)