# Why are all of my folders locked?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, filesystem

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to delete some of my files but I get a message saying "Permission denied", and my files are locked.
How do I unlock them to delete them, or make changes?

[image: pic of locked files]]

Comment: Files outside your /home directory are generally owned by a different user instead of you. You cannot delete their files, they cannot delete your files. Best practice is to save your files to your /home dir, so you own them.

Comment: @user535733 I'm already inside the /home dir, ```/home/usama/EDU/full-stack/grahql-tm```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/usama/EDU/full-stack/grahql-tm/client`?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be the file owner of these folders and files. They may have been created with root access, which a user would not be able to perform modifications.

You can verify this by opening a terminal in that folder by right-clicking on empty space in the folder and selecting "Open in Terminal" :

[image: open in terminal]

You may then find out what the rights and ownership are by typing:

```
ls -alF
```

Then if you need to change the owner of a file you can do:

```
sudo chown $USER the_file
```

You can also change the rights to the file:

```
sudo chmod +rw the_file
```

You may perform both of the aforementioned actions using this one command alternatively:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER the_file
```

You may do a lot of files and folders at once by going to the parent of the highest folder where this happens, opening a terminal at that location and typing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER the_first_problematic_folder/*
sudo chmod -R +rw the_first_problematic_folder/*
```

This should give you back rights to the files.

Unless they are on a network drive and you are not granted rights to modify the rights to these files by the way the drive is mounted.

Follow this answer here : [XAMPP VirtualHost in Other Directory 403 Forbidden Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154402/xampp-virtualhost-in-other-directory-403-forbidden-error/1154512#1154512) for more specifics.

Comment: yup, typo. I added your answer. I think this user is out of his league as-is with the terminal so I found the simplest approach I could. notice I didn't introduce `cd` and instead suggested opening different terminals for each dir, using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at basic file ownership.

Here's a file that I own. I can change it or delete it because I *own* it:

```
    $ ls -l testfile
    -rw-r--r-- 1 frank frank 0 Jul  5 07:12 testfile
                 //Owner is "frank", Group is "frank"
```

Let's change the ownership. Let's give the file to the user 'helen':

```
    $ sudo chown helen:helen testfile    //New owner is "helen", new group is "helen"
    $ ls -l testfile
    -rw-r--r-- 1 helen helen 0 Jul  5 07:12 testfile 
    //See how the ownership has changed?  
    //When owned by helen, I cannot change or delete the file anymore.
    //The lock appears in the GUI icons.
```

Let's change the ownership back to me, so I can make changes and get rid of the lock icons:

```
    $ sudo chown frank:frank testfile
```