# Does sudo really make you root for a while?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, root

On Ubuntu, in what kind of situations, if any, running a command as a non-`root` to access a file/folder or create/delete a file/folder using `sudo` may result in "permission denied"
while running the same command as `root` user would succeed? The user is assumed to be a sudoer, of course.

Practical example on Ubuntu 12: I've got this directory in `/` with `root:root` ownership and `drwxr-xr-x` permissions and I tried `sudo date > file` while in it as well as `sudo date | tee file` but got the same

```
-bash: file: Permission denied
```

in both cases. Sure enough, there're no problems if I'm `root`. This is quite frustrating.

Comment: Yes, it would succeed.

Comment: Running commands on a file without sudo depends on the permissions of the file, whether you're an owner of that file, belong to a group that has permissions for that file, etc. It also depends on what you're doing with it such as viewing, modifying, moving, deleting, running, etc. To see the permissions of a file you have access to in Nautilus, right click it and select Properties, then the Permissions tab. To read about file permissions, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work.

Comment: Does the file to which you pipe have the immutable bit set? See https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Chattr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the command you are trying? A common mistake is `sudo foo > output` which doesn't run the output redirection as root because it's done by the shell. A solution to this one would be `foo | sudo tee output` (or `sudo foo | sudo tee output` if `foo` requires root access)

Comment: My bad, I edited the answer now to have the correct commands

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` lets you run a program as another user - as root by default.

It's the same as if root runs that program (except maybe for some environment variables and such). So there is no such situation.