# Permission drwxrwxr -x

Tags: 12.04, permissions, chmod

I need some help about permission. I had a permission drwxrwxr-x but I try to change the permission with chmod 755 /folder/ and after that I receive permission drwxr-xr-x but I would like to change it back to drwxrwxr-x. Please can you help me with this? 
Filip

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/347680/6969) for a description of the symbolic names. The `d` prefix means that the file in question is a directory. Regular files have a `-` prefix. There are other types too, look in the info page of `ls` for more.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For `drwxrwxr-x` it's:

```
chmod 775  the_path_to_target
```

For `drwxr-xr-x` it's:

```
chmod 755  the_path_to_target
```

Answer (score 28):

allways remember the following

```
r - read
w - write
x - execute
```

and permission matrix is

```
7 = all rights
6 = read and write
5 = read and execute
4 = read only
3 = execute and write
2 = write only
1 = execute only
0 = no rights
```

i think this will help you to understand the permission and by adding **+** you give the permission and **-** you remove the permission

Comment: Very good explaination!

Answer (score 7):

remembering the letter form is easier than the numbers (in my opinion)
for example:

```
chmod a+w file
```

the part before the sign

> the user who owns it (u), other users in the file's group (g), other users not in the file's group (o), or all users (a)

the sign

> The operator + causes the selected file mode bits to be added to the existing file mode bits of each file; - causes them to be removed; and = causes them to be added and causes unmentioned bits  to  be  removed  except that a directory's unmentioned set user and group ID bits are not affected.

the last part

> read (r), write (w), execute (or search for directories) (x)

you can run

```
chmod a+rx file
chmod ug+w file
```