# copy a file in computer folder

Tags: permissions

I try to load the dictionary es-ES.dic in the folder usr\share\myspell\dicts (needed for TEXMAKER) but I am not permited because I am not "owner" How can I solve this?

Comment: Read this first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work

Answer (score 1):

Use command:

First change directory to the folder where the "es-ES.dic" is by using:

$ cd /path

Then copy using:

$ sudo cp -R es-ES.dic /usr/share/myspell/dicts

Answer (score 0):

You need to open nautilus as root, then open the file:

`sudo nautilus /usr/share/myspell/dicts`

Or open the file directly:

`sudo xdg-open /usr/share/myspell/dicts/es-ES.dic`begining

Also, a note. In Ubuntu, file locations use `/` instead of `\` like in windows, and we always put a `/` at the beginning, like the equivalent of `C:\`. So your location should not be written as:

`usr/share/myspell/dicts/` or even `usr\share\myspell\dicts`

But as this:

`/usr/share/myspell/dicts/`