# File Permissions - Please Help

Tags: permissions, samba, file-sharing, groups

So I am delt with a very bad hand. As Windows user for nearly 10 years

I have an assignment which says

**Create 7 users** - 2 admin, 2 teachers and 3 students **[DONE]**

**Create folder in Home** - Admin Files,Teacher Files,Student Files **[Done]**

**Now I have to be able to do this using terminal**

- Allow students read-only access to the files in the Student Files folder, and no access to the other folders.
- Allow teachers full access to all  files except the Admin Files folder, to which they have no access.
- Allow administrators full access to all files.

How do I change the file permission for the scenario above?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work

Comment: This is a homework?

Comment: Yes it part of a assignment

Comment: First, create each groups for students and teachers. And then set directory permission for each group.