# Why does the Unix permission system use 1 2 3 4... values instead of 1 or 0?

Tags: permissions

Why does the Unix permission system use 1 2 3 4... values?

Why not just 3 bits; a bit for each setting read write and execute.
for example

```
( rwx ) 110 => r=1 w=1 x=0
```

Comment: O.o You do realise `4` is three bits? `100`?

Comment: This may shed some light into the matter: https://askubuntu.com/a/347680/3940

Comment: I think he just missinterpreted the usage of the binary and octal display of the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more compact to use integers from 1-7 that are the sum of the following three octal permission representation numbers, 4 (read), 2 (write), and 1 (execute) added together, because all the Unix permissions can be represented by one integer number ranging from 1 to 7 instead of using 3 numbers to represent the Unix permissions.

#### Usage examples

```
Number  Octal Permission Representation                            Ref
0       No permission                                              ---
1       Execute permission                                         --x
2       Write permission                                           -w-
3       Execute and write permission: 1 (execute) + 2 (write) = 3  -wx
4       Read permission                                            r--
5       Read and execute permission: 4 (read) + 1 (execute) = 5    r-x
6       Read and write permission: 4 (read) + 2 (write) = 6        rw-
7       All permissions: 4 (read) + 2 (write) + 1 (execute) = 7    rwx
```

Answer (score 5):

Because we have these 3 bits (r/w/x) 3 times, once for user (owner) permissions, once for group permissions and once for permissions for everybody else.

That is why e.g. in the output of `ls -l` where you get the textual permissions representation, it looks e.g. like `-rwxr-xr-x` (the first `-` just indicating the file type, i.e. whether it is a directory or not).

(Actually there are even three more bits - SUID, SGID and Sticky - but you can look those more advanced permissions up on your own if you are interested.)

Comment: That's exactly it, always remember we are lazy, we don't want to write `chmod 111101000` for just changing one files access... That's why they just shortened it and said we use 3 bits per each owner,group and others. So we now have `chmod 750` instead which is much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

To representing `rwx` it's exactly using 3 (0 or 1) bit:

```
Decimal  |  Binary
--------------------
1        |    001
2        |    010
3        |    011
4        |    100
5        |    101
6        |    110
7        |    111
```

So when you are using "3" you are actually setting the bits on: `011` equal to `-wx`, exactly as you are thinking about it. However don't forget about SUID, SGID and sticky bit as an extra bit.