# What's Linux analog for "everyone" security principal on Windows

Tags: filesystem, security, filemanager

Is there any Linux analog for "everyone" security principal on windows, or the mechanism for really the same effect ?

Comment: See [_How do file permissions work?_](https://askubuntu.com/q/83/504066). The principal you are looking for is _others_.

Comment: PerlDuck, you could post your comment as answer.

Comment: What is the *'"everyone" security principal on windows'*? Many of us here aren't as familiar with Windows as with Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work) given by PerlDuck describes what file permissions are.

Here is a short summary. If you want to give everyone access to a file or directory, you can do this simply by:

```
chmod a+rwx <filename/directoryname>
```

E.g.: Make an empty file with

```
touch myTestFile.txt
```

Now look at the permission settings with

```
ls -l myTestFile.txt
```

or get even more information with

```
stat myTestFile.txt
```

Depending how the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is set, you will get something like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 aaa bbb 0 Jul 12 15:58 myTestFile.txt
```

Here aaa is your username, and bbb is the groupname.

Now you can allow others/all write(w), read(r) or execute(x) access with the following command:

```
chmod o+rwx myTestFile.txt
```

or

```
chmod a+rwx myTestFile.txt
```

The later changes permission to owner, group and others (=all), while the first only change permission to others.

If you are now typing

```
ls -l myTestFile.txt
```

you can see that the permissions have been set.

**Using a gui based file browser**

You can also use a file browser to change file permissions.
For instance on a gnome desktop open **nautilus**,  right-click on a directory/file and change to the permissions tab. You will see a window like the one below. You can now change the permissions for others by clicking on the others-access list.

[image]