# Opening an IDE with write, delete & read permissions?

Tags: permissions, 18.10

Just installed Ubuntu 18.10 and I have realized that when trying to open VS code and save a file it will throw a permission denied error. It also does this when trying to delete files, not only write to them.

I understand you could launch the application as sudo but I've been told this is not advised, could someone tell me what the best way to do this is, without breaking any major rules?

It's my first time with Ubuntu and I've only tried using it as I was told its pretty neat for web development, apologies if this is a novice question and has an easy answer.

Comment: *Where* do you want to save the file? How did you install VS Code?

Comment: I installed VS code in the Ubuntu Software application, I'm trying to save `index.php` in `/var/www/html`, the document root for my website.

Comment: And does your user have access to `/var/www/html`? By default, that directory belongs to `root`.

Comment: How would I check that? I have an admin account if that's what you mean, I am the only user on the computer, made during the installation.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [How do file permissions work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work) and [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: I've tried all solutions in the accepted answer in the above question, I'm still struggling to have access for writing to files. Saving a file makes VS code say `Failed to save 'index.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.`, clicking the retry button simply reiterates the error message.