# Issue with training text classification model in R on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, r

The R code I have is as following, it results an error as below. However, this works fine on my windows local machine. Just error on ubuntu server as below.The generated model.bin file is about 229 MB on my windows local machine. Not sure why I cannot train the model on Ubuntu server, any help would be appreciated!

```
library(fastrtext)

model_file <- build_supervised(documents = data1[["V5"]],
                               targets = data1[["V3"]],
                               model_path = '/srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel',
                               dim = 30, lr = 0.1, epoch = 30, wordNgrams = 2)



Prepare and write tempfile at ... /tmp/RtmpLMf0uE/file9083d9d7650
Starting supervised training with following commands: 
$ supervised -input /tmp/RtmpLMf0uE/file9083d9d7650 -output /srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel -lr 0.1 -dim 30 -ws 5 -epoch 30 -minCount 5 -minCountLabel 0 -neg 5 -wordNgrams 2 -loss ns -bucket 2000000 -minn 3 -maxn 6 -thread 12 -lrUpdateRate 100 -t 0.0001 -label __label__ -verbose 2


Error in model$execute(c("fasttext", commands)) : 
  /srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel.bin cannot be opened for saving.
```

Comment: Sounds like a basic file ownership/permissions issue - see [How do file permissions work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work)

Answer (score 0):

can you show us the authorization settings with the following command

```
sudo ls -l /srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel.bin
```

You can fix the authorization issues by authorizing your user to edit that file

```
sudo chown yourusername /srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel.bin
sudo chmod 700 /srv/shiny-server/text_cls/voc_single/mymodel.bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just put the mymodel.bin file in R working directory which permits the edit authorization and everything works after that.

Comment: @Jason thanks a lot. I remain available for assistance