# Permission Denied: System calls in c

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, c

I am attempting to code and execute bash scripts using C lang. Purpose is for a personal project I'm writing in C, and seeing if I can include bash capabilities as well. I created a simple C file `script.c`(compiled as `script`) for testing, but I am getting the error:

`bash: ./script: Permission denied`

I have tried running with sudo permissions, but still getting similar response:

`sudo: unable to execute ./script: Permission denied`

All I intend to do with this file is run the bash command: `echo "hello"` using C

Here is the C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
        #/bin/bash \n\
        echo \"hello\" \n\
"

int main() {
        puts("executing script");
        system(SHELLSCRIPT);
        return 0;
}
```

My wild guess is that the line with `system(SHELLSCRIPT);` is the cause, being that not even a root user can make system calls. However, after looking through the internet consensus is that it is possible to execute bash scripts in this fashion. Any help or insight is apprecitated.

Comment: Did you `chmod +x ./script` (on the compiled binary) first before trying to execute it directly?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm not a C programmer, and this appears to be either about that (so off-topic here) but on topic at https://stackoverflow.com/ or about [file permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work). If you are unsure, issue the command `ls -l /path/to/script` and [edit] the result into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, returns `sudo: unable to execute ./script: Permission denied` Forgot to put that in the question

Comment: I recommend you **[edit]** this with the exact command you used to compile the "script" program, all messages (if any) from the compiler, the exact command you used to run the program and its full output, `ls -l script`, and `file script`. It seems the program never ran. If you have not done so, please ensure you can compile a .c file located in the same directory as your "script" program--like a simple hello world program--and run the executable, using commands analogous to those you're using for "script". In your **[edit]** you can clarify if that succeeded and give the details if it didn't.

Comment: It works fine for me, exactly as written. Compiled with `cc bla-script.c -o bla-script` (I changed the file name). Executed with `./bla-script`

Comment: @EliahKagan i compiled with gcc: `gcc -o script script.c`

Comment: ... better question, why're you using `sudo` to execute your script which doesn't need elevated privileges?

Comment: Thank you for confirming @DougSmythies
It appears I didn't properly mount the hard drive I'm working in with correct permissions. So some files just won't work outright. This program works when created in a different, correctly mounted, drive.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I didn't properly mount the hard drive I'm working in with correct permissions. So files just won't work outright. This program works when created in a different, correctly mounted, drive.