# Ubuntu 20.04, classic can't drag and drop problem

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, gsettings

Installed 20.04 on 4/23 and can't drag and drop. I've had this issue with previous LTS installs and fixed it by toggling "experimental views" on/off through gsettings. That's not working this time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Drag from where and drop to where? Have you  verified that you have [write permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work) to the drop location?

Comment: From anywhere to anywhere. Example: Documents Folder > Desktop, and vice versa.

Comment: Also, yes, I have read/write permissions for those locations.

Comment: That might be it, yes. Thanks. Although having to replace Nautilus with Nemo seems pretty suboptimal as a long-term solution. If it's currently just a shortcoming of Nautilus, is it likely to be fixed in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seems so. Note that it's not a bug with Nautilus, Nautilus is completely relieved from handling desktop icons as a conscious decision (reasons listed [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158)). It's unlikely that the developers would reverse the decision. We can only hope for the GNOME extension that handles desktop icons now to gain the feature in future.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just wait and "move to" rather than dragging to the desktop.

Comment: It is astonishing that things goes backward and it is surprising that Canonical goes to hit new users with a such basic missing intuitive function. Common people will hang on this and after a brief test of Ubuntu will abandon it in many cases.