Drag and drop URL shortcut from Firefox to file manager to create a .url file
Context: On Windows, I use this simple browser bookmarking system (what I consider the best bookmarking system I have ever tried in decades): just drag and drop the URL from the Firefox URL bar to the Desktop or File Manager: it creates a .url file. So bookmarks can be copied/deleted/moved/organized-in-folders like regular files.  (No need to "export" bookmarks when changing the browser: you already have files!)

I tried on Ubuntu yesterday (don't remember if it was Ubuntu 22 or 24), but it didn't seem to work.
Is there a way to enable this very handy feature on Ubuntu?
Should it be enabled on Firefox or inside the File Manager (Nautilus?) features?
Note: this is not a duplicate of Firefox drag and drop URL, because there it's about dragging from one Firefox window to another, which is totally unrelated to saving a bookmark into file.

please [edit] your question to explain why the linked dupe does not answer your question.

@graham Thanks, it's done now.

This add-on to Firefox seems to meet your expectations


Thank you, I will try it. Do you know why it's not possible out of the box with Ubuntu? I thought it was built-in features (it is for Win).

It's a Mozzila issue rather than Canonical/Linux generically

in my memories @graham, there were problems with drag and drop to/from Desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 (or was it 18.04, or 22.04?), due to some privilege questions between. the user and the window manager. Do you remember what it could be? I cannot find a source/report of that anymore. (Would you have a link?) Here it could be linked with that too?

possibly https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230981/ubuntu-20-04-classic-cant-drag-and-drop-problem Enter a search in the search box at the head of the page to find possible matches
